# Weird TypeError in jython/python?

Tags: python, jython, typeerror

I'm bukkit jython/python plugin programmer. Last few days, I'm struggling with this problem. I have to add an potion effect to an user, it's not problem if I enter effect name, duration and amplifier manually in code, but when I want to get them from config, I get this error:

```
    13:38:20 [SEVERE] Could not pass event PlayerInteractEvent to ItemEffect v1.0
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<iostream>", line 126, in onPlayerInteractEvent
    TypeError: addPotionEffect(): 1st arg can't be coerced to org.bukkit.potion.Poti
    onEffect
```

Here's that part of code:

```
    effectname = section.getString("%s.effect"%currentKey)
    duration = section.getInt("%s.duration"%currentKey)
    durationinticks = duration * 20
    geteffectname = "PotionEffectType.%s"%effectname
    getpotioneffect = "PotionEffect(%s, %i, 1)"%(geteffectname, durationinticks)
    geteffectname = "PotionEffectType.%s"%effectname
    if iteminhand == currentKey:
       event.getPlayer().addPotionEffect(getpotioneffect)
```

When I print getpotioneffect out, I get:

```
    13:38:20 [INFO] PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.SPEED, 600, 1)
```

which is okay, and should work. I tested it without getting informations from config, and it works perfectly... To sum up, code above is not working, but below one works:

```
    getpotioneffect = PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.SPEED, 600, 1)
    if iteminhand == currentKey:
       event.getPlayer().addPotionEffect(getpotioneffect)
```

Link to javadocs of this event!

http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/entity/LivingEntity.html#addPotionEffect(org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffect)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first snippet, `getpotioneffect` is a string. You can check it adding `print type(getpotioneffect)` somewhere.

What you want is to replace this :

```
geteffectname = "PotionEffectType.%s"%effectname
getpotioneffect = "PotionEffect(%s, %i, 1)"%(geteffectname, durationinticks)
```

with this:

```
effect_type = getattr(PotionEffectType, effectname)
potion_effect = PotionEffect(effect_type, durationinticks, 1)
```

Comment: This works like a charm! But why and how? Can you explain it to me if you have some free time?

Comment: Err... Actually this only requires a very very very basic - should I say "minimal" ? - understanding of programming. The _litteral string_ `"PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.SPEED, 600, 1)"` is obviously NOT the same thing as the result of the evaluation of the _source code_ `PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.SPEED, 600, 1)`.